# jQuery reload previous elements after refreshing DIV

Tags: jquery, dom, element, reload

So I have refreshed a DIV - but previous stated elements such as Cufon (font replacement) are not active anymore. How do I achieve this?

```
    // Switch to home.
    $(".switch_home").live('click', function () {

        // Fade content out.
        $("div#content_hldr").fadeOut("fast", function () {

            // Load Home page in.
            $("div#content_hldr").load("content/content.home.php");

            // Cufon.replace('h2'); <----

            // Fade in the content.
            $("div#content_hldr").fadeIn("fast");

        });

    });
```

Commented what should happen, actually. Best scenario, I should be able to reload all previous elements and functions / events.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply Cufon (no idea what that is) to newly loaded-in elements within `$.load`'s callback:

```
$("div#content_hldr").load("content/content.home.php", function() {
    $(".blah").Cufon();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Cufon is a font-replacement. Loading custom fonts as a javascript object.